# How to integrate this cumbersome piece-wise function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

I have this systems of equation:

```
kt = Sqrt[h/(π (y1 - y2))]*Integrate[p[y]*Sqrt[(1 + y)/(1 - y)], {y, -1, 1}]  
kb = Sqrt[h/(π (y1 - y2))]*Integrate[p[y]*Sqrt[(1 - y)/(1 + y)], {y, -1, 1}]
```

In which: `y1` and `y2` are two variables that I need to find, `-1<y2<0`, `0<y1<1`, and `y1` and `y2` are real.

The problem is that `p[y]` is a piece-wise function and is defined by:

```
p[y] := Piecewise[{
    {p + a*(y1 + y2)/2 - a*2 h y/(y1 - y2) - t1, y2 < y < y1}, 
    {p + a*(y1 + y2)/2 - a*2 h y/(y1 - y2) - t2, y1 < y < 1}, 
    {p + a*(y1 + y2)/2 - a*2 h y/(y1 - y2) - t3, -1 < y < y2}}]
```

In which: `a`, `p`, `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `h` are constants.

I need to find `y1` and `y2` so that:

```
kt==c1&&kb==c2
```

where `c1` and `c2` are two constants.

I had tried to solve this integration manually and the answer was lengthy and involved the inverse trigonometric equations. I also tried to use `Solve`, `NSolve`, `Reduce`, `FindInstance` and `NIntegrate` but *Mathematica* usually hangs. Since I have to solve this system of equations repeatedly, I really want to know how can I perform these calculations in *Mathematica* automatically?

Comment: You need an underscore to define a function, like `p[y_]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have certain assumptions regarding the values of `y1` and `y2` but you have not told *Mathematica* about them. If you provide these assumptions to `Integrate`, the symbolic integration proceeds smoothly (taking a couple of minutes):

```
kt = Sqrt[h/(π (y1 - y2))] Integrate[p[y] Sqrt[(1 + y)/(1 - y)], {y, -1, 1}, 
    Assumptions -> {0 < y1 < 1, -1 < y2 < 0}];

kb = Sqrt[h/(π (y1 - y2))] Integrate[p[y] Sqrt[(1 - y)/(1 + y)], {y, -1, 1}, 
    Assumptions -> {0 < y1 < 1, -1 < y2 < 0}];
```

You can then supply values for the parameters and get a result using `FindRoot`:

```
Block[{a = 1, p = 2, t1 = 3, t2 = 4, t3 = 5, h = 6, c1 = -30, c2 = 15},
 FindRoot[{kt == c1, kb == c2}, {y2, -0.5}, {y1, 0.5}]]

(* {y2 -> -0.245106, y1 -> 0.801993} *)
```

Comment: :It works. But, could you explain the elegant idea of specifying the domains of `y1` and `y2`? I still don't get it. And why do you instruct `Mathematica` to start seeking solutions near the point `{-0.5,0.5}`? Is there any specific reason for this?

Comment: @ThanhSon, well if you were doing the integral by hand you would probably split it into integrals from -1 to y2, y2 to y1 and y1 to 1, using the appropriate part of p[y] for each one. You can only do this if you know that `-1 < y2 < y1 < 1`. I expect *Mathematica* makes use of the information in a similar way. `FindRoot` needs a starting value for each parameter, so I just chose the middle of the domain for each. You can also tell `FindRoot` the domain of each parameter like `{y2, -0.5, -1, 0}` but it didn't seem necessary for this case.